# Updating @State var from UIKit

Tags: swiftui, state

I have a SwiftUI that shows two items in a List view. I want to be able push the desired list entry from UIKit. For this purpose, I have created an @State var which I want to set from UIKit to trigger the desired list entry via the binding on the NavigationLink's selection parameter.

```
public struct DateOptions: View, MiscellaneousHelper {
  @State var selectedItem: AppMainFeatureData? = nil

      
      let tabBarController: TabBarController
    
      public var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
          List(AppMainFeatureData.dateItems, id: \.self) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: DateFeatureController(svc: tabBarController.svc, feature: item),
                           tag: item, selection: $selectedItem) {
              ImageText(text: item.title, imageName: item.iconName)
            }
          }
          .navigationBarTitle(SideBarSection.dates.title)
        }
      }
    }
```

Here's my UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
struct DateFeatureController: UIViewControllerRepresentable, MiscellaneousHelper {
  let svc: SplitViewController
  let feature: AppMainFeatureData
  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
    UINavigationController(rootViewController: feature.viewController)
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

The is how I create DateOptions in my UITabBar and how it gets added to the viewControllers:

```
let dateViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: DateOptions(tabBarController: self))
dateViewController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem
viewControllers?.insert(dateViewController, at: 1)
```

Here's how I set selectedItem from a UITabBar:

```
    if let dateFeature = viewControllers?[selectedIndex] as? UIHostingController<DateOptions> {
        dateFeature.rootView.selectedItem = .dateAddSubtract
        dPrint("After \(dateFeature.rootView.selectedItem)")
  }
```

But the print shows selectedItem as nil.

Everything works fine when the the user touches a List entry.

How can I set selectedItem from UIKit?

Comment: Do you have your UIHostingControllers in a 'UIViewRepresentable'? We really need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You should not use State for this purpose, use instead class-based view model confirming to `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Sure. Added UIViewControllerRepresentable.

Comment: @Asperi `StateObject` can be used too